# Multi-master replication - how to fix incorrect credentials problem during connection (ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49))

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, openldap, multi-master-replication

I'm trying to start multi-master replication on two LDAP **ubuntu 16.4** servers (ldap2 and ldap3).
After whole parametrization is done I'm not able to establish the connection between servers:

```
slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://ldap3.rs.local DN="cn=admin,cn=config" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49)
```

The same error in both directions.

Credentials verification using below command is finishing successfully (no errors):

```
ldapmodify -H ldap://ldap3.rs.local -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W
```

I have read all existing tutorials and forums without result.

I will be thankfull for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I've fixed the problem.
In below update, for each host, credentials value must have ADMIN_PASSWORD filled

```
 dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
    changetype: modify
    add: olcSyncRepl
    olcSyncRepl: rid=001 provider=ldap://ldap1.example.local binddn="cn=admin,cn=config" bindmethod=simple credentials=ADMIN_PASSWORD searchbase="cn=config" type=refreshAndPersist retry="5 5 300 5" timeout=1
    olcSyncRepl: rid=002 provider=ldap://ldap2.example.local binddn="cn=admin,cn=config" bindmethod=simple credentials=ADMIN_PASSWORD searchbase="cn=config" type=refreshAndPersist retry="5 5 300 5" timeout=1

-
add: olcMirrorMode
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
```

In tutorial this value was equal to "test" and somehow I've missed it